# Phrase: to deepen offence

Tags: verbs, verb-forms

Considering the phrase

> "to deepen offence"

I mean to say "to increase offence". Is that correct? Can I use it in a sentence?

For example:

> "This situation may even deepen his offence."

Comment: Probably yes, but we'd need more context to be definitive.

Comment: Do you mean offense in the sense of being offended, (in which case @J.R. answered your question very well below)  or in the sense of having committed an offense? _"As it happened, there was a sleeping baby in the back seat of the car he stole.  This situation deepened his offense."_

Answer (score 3):

> "This situation may even deepen his offence."

That doesn't sound very natural to me. I think it would be better to simply say:

> This situation may offend him even more deeply.

You could change the word *his* to *the*, and that could work in some contexts:

> Jane was rightfully offended when nobody thanked her for her volunteer work. But, when they didn't bother to invite her to the appreciation banquet, that deepened the offense.